Replacing ArcObjects IGxDialog in ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK
My current development environment is a .NET Forms application coded against .NET 6.0.
I'm developing a standalone client toolset within which I need to be able to locate and identify pathing to GIS data on the file system, including feature classes within file geodatabases.  Within ArcObjects, this requirement was met by the old IGxDialog component.  However, I've been unable to locate any suitable replacement or feasible workflow leveraging the ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET standalone libraries (ArcGIS.Core; ArcGIS.CoreHost).
Is there a way to do this?
I looked into ArcGIS Maps SDK for .NET and this is not what I'm needing since it appears to be targeted for solutions surrounding ArcGIS Online implementations.  I'm specifically looking for an Esri solution to navigate to local GIS data in a standalone toolset.

You mean like the OpenItemDialog?

I believe so yes.  Unfortunately, that library is not exposed for standalone CoreHost applications.  It's only available from within the ArcGIS Pro app (at least to my understanding at this point).
